# Render JSON instead of HTML as default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rendering

I try to tell rails 3.2 that it should render JSON by default, and kick HTML completely like this:

```
respond_to :json    

def index
  @clients = Client.all
  respond_with @clients
end
```

With this syntax, I have to add `.json` to the URL. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can modify your `routes.rb` files to specify the default format

**routes.rb**

```
resources :clients, defaults: {format: :json}
```

This will modify the default response format for your entire `clients_controller`

Comment: Can this be added globally for all resources?

Comment: To add default format to all resources, declare resources in a `defaults` block: `defaults format: 'json' {resources :clients; resources :products}`.

Comment: is this compatible with newer rails version ? I add the line you mentiond but it still render HTML. could you please explain me how can I do this sir ? thanks

Comment: This is great, you can also apply it to namespaces (and probably scopes, etc).  For example `namespace :api, { defaults: { format: :json } } do`.  Im currently doing that on Rails 5

Comment: thanks @Ryan, that is what exactly I was looking for 

Answer (score 16):

This pattern works well if you want to use the same controller actions for both.  Make a web version as usual, using :html as the default format.  Then, tuck the api under a path and set :json as the default there.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :products

  scope "/api", defaults: {format: :json} do
    resources :products
  end

end
```

Answer (score 11):

If you don't need RESTful responding in your index action then simply render your xml response directly:

```
def index
  render json: Client.all
end
```

Comment: @Tronic Maybe I didn't understand you correctly. I thought your action `index` shouldn't respond to html at all and you want it to respond to json even w/o .json in your url.

Comment: this is a valuable alternative to @rogeilog 's answer for those who don't want to override the default response for ALL of their controller, but just for a certain action

Answer (score 1):

Extending Mark Swardstrom's answer, if your rails app is an API that always returns JSON responses, you could simply do

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope '/', defaults: { format: :json } do
    resources :products
  end
end
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for devise. You'll have to manually set the defaults: `devise_for :users, defaults: {format: :json}`