# Rails 4 - rendering JSON from a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having the worst time rendering a .json.erb file from my controller while being able to test it with RSpec. I have api_docs/index.json.erb and the following controller:

```
class ApiDocsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    render file: 'api_docs/index.json.erb', content_type: 'application/json'
  end
end
```

The explicit `render file` line seems unnecessary, but if I don't do that or `render template: 'api_docs/index.json.erb'`, then I get an error about "Missing template api_docs/index". Likewise if I do have to pass the file name, it sucks even more that I have to give the exact directory--Rails should know that my ApiDocsController templates live in the api_docs directory.

If I have `render file` or `render template`, then I can visit the page and get the JSON contents of my index.json.erb file, as expected. However, this RSpec test fails:

```
let(:get_index) { ->{ get :index } }

...

describe 'JSON response' do
  subject {
    get_index.call
    JSON.parse(response.body)
  }

  it 'includes the API version' do
    subject['apiVersion'].should_not be_nil
  end
end
```

It fails on the `JSON.parse(response.body)` line and if I `raise response.body`, it's an empty string. If I do `render json: {'apiVersion' => '1.0'}.to_json` in the controller, then the test passes just fine.

So, how can I always render the JSON template when I go to /api_docs (without having to put `.json` at the end of the URL), and in a way that works both in the browser and in my RSpec test? And can I render the template without having to have some long `render` call in which I pass the full path of the view?

Comment: I wonder if this might not answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681816/render-json-instead-of-html-as-default

Comment: I found that a minute ago and it helped: I can go to /api_docs instead of /api_docs.json and see the JSON in the browser, but the RSpec test still fails because `response.body` is an empty string.

Comment: [This RSpec issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/477) might be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of my solution was based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10682238/38743) to another question: adding `defaults: {format: :json}` to my routes file lets me go to /api_docs and see the JSON when the action is just `def index ; end` with no `render`. The RSpec test still fails though. The full line from my routes file: `resources :api_docs, only: [:index], defaults: {format: :json}`.

Thanks to [this guy](http://ionburn.com/post/33774819654/getting-rspec-to-test-controllers-rendering-json-views) with the same problem and [his gist](https://gist.github.com/jayncoke/4a7c1a67fdc464ad66e8), I added `render_views` to my `describe` block and got my test to pass:

```
describe ApiDocsController do
  render_views

  ...

  let(:get_index) { ->{ get :index } }

  describe 'JSON response' do
    subject {
      get_index.call
      JSON.parse(response.body)
    }

    it 'includes the API version' do
      subject['apiVersion'].should_not be_nil
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually since you're already using `respond_to :json` in your controller you can use just a `render` method to choose your template and, as you probably know, if the template have the same name of the controller method you should be able to suppress the whole `render` method.

If you just remove the `render` line, what's the result?

Comment: Going to /api_docs results in `Missing template api_docs/index`. I have to go to /api_docs.json.

Comment: Oh, I missed your mention that you need to render a json template too, sorry.
Well then you should be able to say something like `render 'api_docs/index.json'` or `render 'index.json'`

Comment: It's entirely a JSON template, actually: I never want to render HTML from this action.

Comment: That answer is kind of ugly because it's still specifying the full path in the `render` call, which seems unnecessary. My template file isn't a partial, and definitely rendering it as `template` or `file`  worked in the browser, but the RSpec test gets an empty JSON response.

Comment: Did you try to remove the .erb of the end of the template? I know this can sound weird but I believe you don't need it and it can influence the RSpec test, since you have a "html with a json inside" which probably doesn't work properly with `JSON.parse`

Comment: Just tried that, so I had `index.json`. The JSON still rendered correctly in the browser, but the RSpec test still fails with `JSON::ParserError: A JSON text must at least contain two octets!` because the `response.body` is blank.

Comment: Ok so it seems that the controller <> template relationship is working properly, could it be something with the way the spec is asserting the response? What's the return of a `raise response.to_yaml`?

Comment: I solved my problem with the test--see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18621427/38743) above. It was indeed an RSpec thing: I had to add a `render_views` call in my test.

Comment: Glad to know you found it out =)